# How to install ssh2 extension on PHP5.6 on windows

Tags: php, ssh, openssh

The link http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/
only has ssh2 extension up to PHP5.5. So how can I install the extension on 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net

It's a pure implementation of ssh2 in php, no other extensions (except openssl) are required.

Just put it in your include path and that's it.

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');

?>
```